# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: message.channel.fetchMessages is not a function

Tags: javascript

i get this error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: message.channel.fetchMessages is not a function
```

on this line

```
const fetched = await message.channel.fetchMessages({limit: deleteCount});
```

Anyone know how to fix that?
i am not good with the new updates. hehe.

Comment: If you are using discord.js (please add it in your question's tags, btw) there is no `fetchMessages` function.

Answer (score 7):

What you are trying to state no longer is in the Discord v12 code. Or it's just redefined as this:

**message.channel.messages.fetch**

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the rest of your code it's a bit tricky to be 100% positive, but as the error message says, you're trying to call (Invoke) a nonexisting function `fetchMessages`. Probably `fetchMessages` is defined as a property in `message.channel` and not as a function.

Answer (score 0):

here is rest of the command code

```
if(command === "purge") {

const deleteCount = parseInt(args[0], 10);

if(!deleteCount || deleteCount < 2 || deleteCount > 100)
  return message.reply("Please provide a number between 2 and 100 for the number of messages to delete");

const fetched = await message.channel.fetchMessages({limit: deleteCount});
message.channel.bulkDelete(fetched)
  .catch(error => message.reply(`Couldn't delete messages because of: ${error}`));
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Changing this:

```
const fetched = await message.channel.fetchMessages({limit: deleteCount});
```

to this:

```
const fetched = await message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: deleteCount});
```

Should do the trick!